# Django MongoEngine embedded document issue

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using MongoEngine with Django. In my Django app, I want to create the following embedded document field:

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, StringField, DateTimeField, \
    IntField, EmbeddedDocumentField, BooleanField, ListField

class Person(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    gender = BooleanField()
    birth_date = DateTimeField()
    death_date = DateTimeField()
    parents = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Person))
```

I went to test my code in the python shell, and I received the following error:

```
>>> from models import Person
Traceback (most recent call last):
...(cut for brevity)...
parents = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Person))
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

In terms of MongoDB schema design, this should be a perfectly valid schema, but MongoEngine doesn't seem to like it. Can someone explain what the issue here is and how to avoid it in a nice way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MongoEngine; it is a simple Python scoping issue. `Person` is not defined until the body of the class has finished executing, which means you can't use that name in that class body itself.

MongoEngine does however have a workaround, as the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields) explains; use the string `'self'` instead.